# Supermicro IPMI sensors not present after shutdown

Tags: ipmi, supermicro

i have a supermicro machine with IPMI, and normally the sensors would read the temperature even if the machine is shutdown.

Now i had to update the BIOS and the firmware and now, if you shutdown the server the sensors are not present.

Comment: Can you contact the remote management web interface? Have you tried resetting the RM module?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I can use the webinterface and did factory resets in the console. 
But i don't know what a RM module is..

Answer (score 1):

Did you boot into BIOS after your shutdown?

IPMI can't read the sensors if someone else is reading them at the same time, and BIOS is reading them (directly in the hardware) as long as you're booted into BIOS setup.

Exit BIOS and see if your sensors start showing values again, now when nothing is blocking IPMI from reading the sensors.